# What is battery life on the android device sign into google account vs not sign into google account?

Tags: android, operating-system

I am trying to find out if there is any different between battery for the device that is signed in to google vs the one not signed into google account. I understand that Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is one of the efficient way of transmit data. I would want to know if the device that is not sign into google account would be waking up the device more often than the device did not sign into google account.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the logs what your device is doing. I bet it would have a very low impact, but it seems it would depend on app implementation, as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html):

It would be nice to have the application waiting to have an active data connection, but I haven't found any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better with GCM. Because most of the applications that require a sync with a server will take advantage of GCM and make requests only somethings happens on th server, but if you don't have GCM, some application will make repeated requests to ensure a sync state.